# Cycles bevel node Set on Wood texture

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I have set up of Nodes with wooden texture for a wooden box. I want the box to have a slight bevel, so I added the bevel node since I'm going to render with cycles. When I plug the bevel into the vector of the image map, the texture disappears. What other nodes do I need to add?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The Normal output should be attached to the Normal input of the Principled BSDF. You'll have to combine the values with your current normal map.

Comment: Hello, you just have to drag the bevel node between the "Normal Map" node and the "Bump" node. Also, set the normal map texture node to "non-color data" instead of "sRGB"

Comment: Hey guys, I think I set it up correctly, but the bevel is not very obvious on the edges. https://ibb.co/Cn7sK7J

Comment: Is the non color data selected only for that specific image correctly?